# Hard drive disappeared

Tags: drivers, partitioning, hard-drive, mint

My laptop has ubuntu 22 installed but I wanted one more Linux alongside so I was trying to install mint but when I try doing that the hard drive is not detected by the live USB. So I tried to write the USB using a different application. Didn't work. Then I tried a doing both steps with Debian. Didn't work. But when I try to do the same with a Ubuntu USB it displays the hard drive in gparted. I don't want two ubuntu alongside each other. I also tried partitioning it in various formats. Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: There might be some security system in your computer's UEFI-BIOS system, that is only managed by Ubuntu. Please check what security-related that you can turn off and try again.

Comment: Thanks but that did not work. I have went in-out through every combination in the BIOS. What security are you talking about?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Also be aware the Ubuntu products using the year format, eg. 22, are different to the far more widely used year.month eg. 22.04 systems - they install differently too with less choice for 22 as compared the multiple installers available for 22.04*

Comment: It seems your problem is more difficult than turning off some protection in the  UEFI-BIOS system. I think you get better help at forums dedicated to the Linux distro that you try to boot. (We who help here know Ubuntu best, but cannot be expected to know the current details about other distros, and we need not help you with Ubuntu, because it is already working for you.)

Comment: @guiverc Windows can block drives in dual boot scenarios when u just reboot from windows into Linux. Is there perhaps a similar feature implemented in ubuntu? Might it be that ubuntu is blocking the other distros from accessing it? This is a ubuntu question in that case.

Comment: Some *fs* are more difficult to detect, ie. using *install alongside* and the other OS is using *btrfs*, and no dual-boot grub option maybe offered depending on what was installed (Ubuntu ISOs are available using `ubiquity`, *di*, `subiquity`, `calamares` & *canary* so results may vary on OS/release/ISO used; that issue isn't Ubuntu specific though - but relates to file-system chosen where *btrfs* is not a Ubuntu default; it's optional)

Comment: @guiverc I think we do not understand each other. But THX for your explaination. I was referring to the windows mechanism that prevents Linux from accessing it. You encounter that when you reboot from windows 10 into whatever Linux for example as described here: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/No-disk-Cant-s-see-disk-from-Linux-Boot-Live-Can-t-install/m-p/7183481/highlight/true#M565729   *That's because MS introduced a new form of Hibernation with Wih10 that keeps the Win10 volumes MOUNTED even when Win10 is running.*

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I don't know what windows does to *block drives in dual boot* so I can't given any opinion on that; but I don't see Ubuntu or GNU/Linux generally doing anything like that... Ubuntu very much follows the open standards (*including those by Microsoft*) so they'd only do what *written/published* standards allowed for  (*in comparison or historically; Microsoft have published a standard and not always followed it, or gone beyond etc what the standard allowed for...*)

Comment: @guiverc I was editing my comment while you posted. Reread pls. I just wanted to say: if vladimov would have asked in a windows forum they would have answered Linux is offtopic.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux an example I'm thinking of (*which you won't likely know*), but Ubuntu ISOs carry a *patch* to allow some old non-standards-compliant boxes to boot, that *patch* however is causing problems for other uEFI boxes that follow the standard perfectly..  *kinetic* & later will likely not have those patches & thus not boot on boxes that aren't standards compliant.. as the choice for Ubuntu is usually to follow standards as close as possible.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I didnt know that, thanks.